# Hudson build fails due to SVNAuthenticationException

Tags: java, svn, build, continuous-integration, hudson

I am getting an unexpected error when trying to build a project with Hudson. I have a valid account with which I can checkout to the machine on which Hudson is installed. I have updated from Hudson UI the authentication parameters to this account.

Has anyone else encountered this?

```
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on https://SVN Location
        at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:157)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:99)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:504)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:621)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1095)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
        at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1280)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:139)
    Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: OPTIONS of '/SVN Location': 403 Forbidden (https://SVN)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:610)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:273)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:261)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:178)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicClient.java:482)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.getLocations(SVNBasicClient.java:851)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.createRepository(SVNBasicClient.java:534)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:1016)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:891)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:823)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:145)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say your credentials for accessing the SVN repository are wrong.

Comment: @ATaylor I have manually run a svn checkout command on that machine, with those credentials, and it works fine.

Comment: Doesn't change the facts...it says 'Forbidden', which means it was able to connect, but you are not allowed to access this repository.

Comment: @ATaylor I have committed files with that account from my local machine.

Comment: Okay, allow me to ask this way around...do you have access rights to the options of the SVN repository? Because the way I understand it, the query fails just there...when you're trying to retrieve the options.

Comment: @ATaylor Yes; I have run the command on the Hudson machine: "svn checkout --username usr --password pass http://link" which uses the options --username and --password.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.  And after spending a day researching ssl and http interactions, I discovered that it was in fact an authentication problem.

in jenkins v1.534
the (encrypted) credentials in

```
/opt/jenkins/jobs/JOBNAME/subversion.credentials
```

and

```
/opt/jenkins/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml
```

Were out of date AND out of sync.  And to make diagnosis more difficult they were cached, and overwritten every time I ran a job.  So I had to restart the jenkins service every time I changed those files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the correct URL for SVN. This is a common error when the capitalization is not correct. Maybe the URL is not SVN_Location but Svn_location